# Error ORA-00904 while having Faceted Search With multiple facets search Items

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using **APEX 21.1** and I am facing the below error while running a page having two regions (Faceted Search and Classic Report) :

**Error in Page:**

```
Ajax call returned server error ORA-00904: "APPS"."HR_API": invalid identifier for .
```

**Error in Debug:**

```
APEX - Column Gender, referenced by facet P24_G, is not available or unauthorized. - Contact your application administrator. ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1370 ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1405
```

The error is happening only when I am adding more than one facet item in the Faceted Search.

Can anyone let met know is if it is a bug or not?

Note that I am using a DB view from a different Schema in the Classic Report.

Comment: Well, error says that there's no column HR_API in table APPS. Is there?

Comment: Yes It is there already .. as I mentioned it is not working if a new Facet is added (more than 1 facet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this error since I am using a DB view in a different schema in my classic report

**Oracle Answer:**

> with views or objects in other schemas, it often helps to rewrite the
> report query to use the MATERIALIZE hint, e.g. as follows:

```
with myquery as (
    select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ {your query}
)
select * from myquery
```